# Field default timestamp set to table creation time instead of row creation time

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy, alembic

Using SQLAlchemy, alembic and postgres, when trying to set a column to the row creation time what I finally get is a field that defaults to the time when the table itself was created, instead of the time when the row was created.

Model code:

```
datetime = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
```

Alembic translates it to:

```
sa.Column('datetime', sa.DateTime(), server_default='now()', nullable=False),
```

And the column in Postgres:

```
datetime  | timestamp without time zone | not null default '2013-06-24 11:28:14.930524'::timestamp without time zone
```

What should I do so that the default is the row creation time?

Comment: Rather then submit a proper answer, can you just try `server_default=func.now` instead of `server_default=func.now().

Comment: @Doobeh: I thought of that, and it would make sense as what it's intended to pass is a function instead of a value, but it seems that calling the function is the way to do in in SQLAlchemy. Trying that triggers the following error: sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Argument 'arg' is expected to be one of type '<type 'basestring'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ClauseElement'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression.TextClause'>', got '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression._FunctionGenerator'>'

Comment: Was a bit of a shot in the dark-- I'm used to using  `default=datetime.now` for describing my timestamped columns.  I found (and tested) a solution using `server_default` which I'll leave as the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Aha, worked it out-- seems you need to tell the server_default command if you're sending in some SQL that needs to be executed on the DBMS itself:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

class Test(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=text('now()'))
```

That generates:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
    created TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT now(), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that afterwards. But this will work only for Postgres, right?

Comment: You're just telling it 'Hey, don't process this bit, just add it onto the SQL DDL for this column, no questions asked'.  If your DBMS uses, say, `OMG_RIGHT_NOW()` instead of `NOW()` then you'd need to adjust it.

Comment: The latest SQLAlchemy docs are much clearer about this; for example, see [the 1.13 docs on server_default](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html?highlight=server_default#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_default)